# Changing name to get job

Tags: interviewing, job-search, name

A month ago I sent my application for a job for X company for a full-stack job. They didn't move forward with my application because I am not senior level. I found a new DevOps job. I tried to call the HR person to apply for the job but he did not respond to my call or email. I use my nickname, alternate email and my home phone number to apply for the job.

I want to ask if changing my name to a nickname or alternate email is viewed as a scam, can I get into trouble if someone found out?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? If you're blacklisted, then they'll find out and they'll rescind their offer. If they're so disorganized that just because you have the same name and they couldn't process your application to another role, then you don't want to work for them.

Comment: @NinjaDeveloper,  It is best to keep your accurate info on your resume when applying for a job. If that company likes your accurate resume for the DevOps position, they will move forward. If they don't, you can always apply at other companies.  There are many other companies out there.  Keep everything simple, and you will be happy. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to ask if changing my name to a nickname or alternate email is scam can I get into trouble if someone found out?

"Scam" is probably too strong a word - but ultimately you're asking whether attempting to circumvent the company's prior knowledge of you via obfuscating who you are is okay. You aren't *lying* (yet) but you aren't exactly being 100% honest either.

Let's take this a bit further - say they bring you in for an interview under the "new" details (nickname etc) and during that interview they ask you if you are the same person who applied for the other job. What are you going to say? Do you tell the truth? If you do and they then follow up with asking why you used different details this time around what are you going to say?

If you persist in the pretense that you are a *different* person to the original application how long do you plan on keeping that up? How long do you think you *can* keep that up? Getting rejected for lacking skills isn't a big deal, it happens all the time and is rarely personal. Getting discovered engaging in shennaigans and then getting canned with prejudice **is** a big deal.

All of this based on an *assumption* that you are being stonewalled unfairly for the DevOps role based on you prior application. You say they rejected that based on lack of senior-level skills/experience, how do you know they aren't just dismissing you for similar reasons this time around?

You're acting as if this HR person is some evil mustache-twirling villain keeping you from a job there for, well, *reasons* and if the plucky hero (you) can just outfox them you'll get to work  there and everything will be sunshine and light while they stand and the side impotently shaking their fist muttering "next time, Gadget!". But life isn't a movie or a cartoon - you've sent your details in for a a couple of jobs and they didn't pan out. It sucks, but it's something that happens day in day out so don't over-invest - keep your head down and keep applying for different jobs at different companies and something **will** pan out for you, and then, sooner than you think, you'll have forgotten all about X company. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

> I want to ask if changing my name to a nickname or alternate email is scam can I get into trouble if someone found out?

**No it can't.**

But eventually, you will have to give them your real full legal name for a background check.  If your issue is a single HR person, then this will work.  If you've been blocked by the company and HR is enforcing it, you'll be found out at the background check stage.

Comment: I am not changing my legal name. just using my first name and family name. without my middle name

Comment: if the HR person is not helping because of his/her own black-list. that is not fair